# Textview Visibility using Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am trying the below Usecase :

1. There are Two Items in the List
2. Two TextViews / Button are displayed in a List ( RecyclerView )
3. First TextView / Button is Clicked
4. Second TextView / Button needs to be Hidden ( Toggle the Visibility ) after clicking on First TextView

[image]

I am not able to achieve this functionality using Data Binding. Suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Your question is that much clear for me but in general:

```
<TextView
   android:visibility="@{user.firstName != null ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE} 
   ...
</TextView>
```

Supposing that you use User class and depending on a property you can switch visibility of a view:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
      <data>
          <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
       </data>
        <!-- ... rest of layout here -->
</layout>
```

If you want to achieve this with a button, you might need to update the property as OnClick action of the button.

Comment: If i am clicking on the First TextView, Visibility of the Second TextView needs to be toggled